Colouring instances based on mesh island
I’m currently working on building a city (I have been for a while now). I’m using Blender 3.6 because the shader I use isn’t compatable with 4
I’m using the buildify add-on and have built my own building parts to feed it. I’m editing the Buildify Geonodes setup to suit my purposes. But I’m wondering if it’s possible to give the same colour value to all instances on each mesh island - and have all mesh island’s random colours.
I already have a colour change shader setup which works nicely, feeding a stored named attribute into the shader to drive colours from a ramp:


This works nicely, giving all instances a different colour:

I’ve tried a few different methods to try and assign the same colour to mesh islands, as buildify creates a new building on each island. Here’s me trying the mesh island node in place of the index/domain nodes:

However this just makes all instances the same colour across all islands:

Is what I am trying to do possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Question: (I don't have buildify) - Is it "mesh island" or is it "instance"? They're different things.

So, assuming you have:

A "mesh" that contains islands; and
You're adding "instances" to that mesh

You need to store the attribute before instancing (while you still have a "mesh" and only the mesh). Then the attribute will transfer automatically to the instances:

